# Conditional SELECT in Lambda expression LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on the following:
I need to select different values (in my case Adapters) based on different conditions, I tried like this:

```
return this.WrappedEntity.human_screen.SelectMany(e => e).Select(e =>
                {
                    AHuman human = _unitOfWork.HumansRepo.GetById(e.human_uid.ToString());
                    if (e.vid_screen == "1" && human.Gender== Gender.Female)
                    {
                        return new SqlFemaleScreening(e);
                    }
                    else if (e.vid_screen == "1" && human.Gender== Gender.Male)
                    {
                        return new SqlMaleScreening(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new SqlChildScreening(e);
                    }
                });
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: Type arguments for method "`System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany
>   <TSource,TResult> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TSource>,
>   System.Func <TSource, int, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   <TResult>>)` "should be defined for use. Try to clearly define the
>   type arguments.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I assume that when you say "it is not correct" you mean that there is a  compiler error of some kind? What does it say?

Comment: How is it 'not correct'? What's the error?

Comment: What is wrong with it? Does it throw an exception or you are concerned with code quality?

Comment: Is it because human.Gender? is that supposed to be part of the WrappedEntity?

Comment: ERROR: Type arguments for method "System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany <TSource,TResult> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TSource>, System.Func <TSource, int, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <TResult>>) "should be defined for use. Try to clearly define the type arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that because you are returning multiple different types of objects the compilers isn't sure what objet type you are expecting in your returned enumerable. Usually when you use something like `Select` or `SelectMany` the compiler can work it out so you don't need to worry about it. In this case you need to worry about telling it what they should be.

Your code will be changed to look like:

```
return this.WrappedEntity.human_screen.SelectMany(e => e).Select<TSource, TResult>(e =>
     {
         //Same code as before in here
     });
```

`TSource` should be the type of `e` in your select method. `TResult` should be the base type of `SqlFemaleScreening`, `SqlMaleScreening`, `SqlChildScreening`.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I do not have base type of SqlFemaleScreening, SqlMaleScreening, SqlChildScreening adapters.

Comment: What return type are you expecting then? Obviously you get an `IEnumerable<T>` out of these things and what you need to do is define what T is in a way that all the classes can fit into it. If they have no common type then I'm not sure what the benefit of putting them all in the same enumerable is (and the names really do suggest they *should* have a common type since they sound really rather similar...

Comment: Right, thanks! Now it works, but without SelectMany:return this.WrappedEntity.human_screen.Select<human_screen, Screening>(e => 
                {}

Answer (score 0):

Result of SelectMany expression should be `IEnumerable<T>`, e.g.

```
human_screen.SelectMany(e => e.Some_Collection)
```